# SyntaxError in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to follow the django tutorial, (chapter 4, http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html). But the code further below throws a syntax error.

error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:1222/hello/
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    invalid syntax (views.py, line 23)
Exception Location: /home/milad/djangobook/djangobook/urls.py in <module>, line 2
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from djangobook.views import hello, showtime, plustime

urlpatterns = patterns('',('^hello/$',hello),('^time/$',showtime),(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$',plustime),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
import datetime 

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse ("Hello Dear Django!")

def showtime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = get_template('showtime.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'time':now}))
    return HttpResponse(html)

def plustime(request,plus):
    try:
        plus = int(plus)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()
    now = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=plus)
    t = get_template('plustime.html')   
    html = t.render(Context({'plus1':now})
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: For future reference: the Django 500 error page gives you the option to view the traceback as a copyable traceback; there is a link on the error page, click on that and then copy the whole traceback of the error to your question. I was able to do a quick count of your lines in `view.py` but the traceback would have helped to pinpoint the exact problem faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line:

```
html = t.render(Context({'plus1':now})
#          --- 1     --2          -- 2 but no 1
```

add `)` at the end there:

```
html = t.render(Context({'plus1':now}))
```